# "Один" объект без singleton

Tags: php, ооп, dependency-injection, singleton

Как можно по всему проекту использовать только 1 объект, не используя паттерн синглтон? Или это единственное решение?

Мне нужно решить следующую задачу:

```
$logger = new Monolog\Logger('someName');

$errHandler = new Monolog\ErrorHandler($logger);
$errHandler->registerErrorHandler(); 
$errHandler->registerExceptionHandler();
$errHandler->registerFatalHandler();

$logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\StreamHandler('logs.log'));
$logger->pushProcessor(new Monolog\Processor\PsrLogMessageProcessor());
$logger->pushProcessor(new Monolog\Processor\MemoryPeakUsageProcessor());
$logger->pushProcessor(new Monolog\Processor\IntrospectionProcessor());
// ... и другие конфигурации логирования
```

Таким образом создается и сконфигурированный экземпляр класса логирования, который Я планирую использовать для своего проекта.

Как мне сделать, чтобы при использования логирования в разных местах проекта (в разных файлах, классах, ..), не приходилось каждый раз создавать новый экземпляр класса и конфигурировать его - это наверняка не правильно (как минимум это не удобно).

Ранее мне предлагали создание экземпляра класса и его конфигурацию запихнуть в отдельный файл, и подключать где-нибудь в начале проекта.
Мне такой вариант не нравится, т.к.объект будет инициализирован в любом случае, не важно, используется оно или нет. Т.е. необходим lazy-load.

Насколько я понимаю, хорошо бы первым делом обернуть конфигурацию и создание объекта логирования в какой-нибудь враппер?

Дальше если решить вопрос lazy-load через DI контейнер, то получится, при использовании (вытаскивании объекта логирования) из DI-контейнера в разных файлах проекта, будет каждый раз создаваться новый объект.. Это мне не мешает. Код будет и дальше работать, создавая новые объекты логирования. Но здравый смысл подсказывает, что это ни есть хорошо. Почему бы не использовать тот объект, который уже создан ?

Вопрос в следующем, как можно добиться такого результата? Уже задавал кучу разных вопросов тут.. Читал много статей про DI-контейнеры. Но никто не смог внятно объяснить..  Как можно добиться такого результата, что для этого нужно сделать.

По сути, всю проблему решит singleton-wrapper (в котором буду создавать объект логирования и конфигурировать его). Как можно тоже самое сделать без синглтона?

И еще, "вопрос в вопросе", когда мы используем DI-контейнер, то получается, что он не 1 для всего проекта? В каждом файле проекта нужно его заного объявлять и задавать сервисы и их зависимости? Есть ли какие-то решение, чтобы можно было в начале проекта описать свои сервисы из сконфигурировать, и использовать так где это необходимо?

Большая просьба помочь, объяснить как это работает. Уже не первую неделю ищу ответы на свои вопросы. Буду благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

**Все зависиот от структуры проекта.**

Если это классическое спагетти, отдельные похапе файлы на каждую операцию, то синглетон будет самой меньшей из проблем. Используй на здоровье.

Если это классическая "MVC" иерархия с кдиной точкой входа, где объекты создаются на лету ядром, то вот при этом создании и используем объекты из контейнера.

Comment: Структура проекта - MVC, все классы подключаются через autoloader composer'a по psr-4.

Вы предлагаете использовать контейнер: а контейнер должен быть глобальным? Как мне в одном месте проекта добавить в контейнер сервис, а в других местах его получать?  Получается, что контейнер должен быть либо глобальным, статическим или иметь класс-обертку singleton?

Я могу создать контейнер в единой точке входа, но в дальнейшем столкнусь с проблемой при получении сервиса логирования, когда еще не будет существовать в нем такого сервиса. 

Можно пожалуйста примеры?

Comment: Я говорю об объектах, а не о классах. Автолоадер здесь не при чем.  Я не понимаю, что значит "Я могу создать контейнер в единой точке входа, но в дальнейшем столкнусь с проблемой при получении сервиса логирования, когда еще не будет существовать в нем такого сервиса."

Comment: Судя по вопросу, в частности по фразе "В каждом файле проекта", у вас все-таки не MVC с единой точкой входа, а до боли родное спагетти. Так что не парьтесь а используйте синглтон. А при случае попробуйте освоить Симфони. Это будет в 100 раз полезнее, чем 10 ответов на ваши вопросы.